# Tableau Fill Certain Countries on Map and Also add Lat Long Points to Map

Tags: tableau-api

I have a set of latitude and longitude points that I plot on the tableau map.  In addition to that, I want to fill some of the countries on the map. The lat long points are not necessarily in the countries I want to fill. Some of them are and some aren't.

I can do these things separately, but not on the same map.

How do I do this?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following, assuming you are using Tableau geocoding for the filled map countries.
Make the filled map chart with the generated lat/lon fields on the columns and row shelves. When you are happy with that and ready to add your points, then ...

Add the latitude and longitude fields for your data (which I assume differ from the generated ones) to the columns and row shelves. Select both new lat/lon pills separately and choose dual axis.

You should get multiple sets of marks cards that you can edit to revise your visualization.